# Block/limit/filter addresses or email address?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, payment, customer-address

We've been targeted apparently by a group that's testing stolen card numbers against our store. We've asked Paypal (our processor) for help and they've pretty much told us we're on on own.

The "test" orders thus far all seem to be using the same street address and email address, but I can't find any way to block these. A google search for

> Magento Block \anything else\

is rather unhelpful in this case since the term "block" is used extensively in magento's internal structure.

Is there any way to setup some rules, filters, etc in Magento to automatically reject orders that meet certain criteria (such as a known-bad list of emails, names, addresses, etc) and preferably toss up a generic "Bad Credit Card" error such as not to tip off our fraudster?

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not have this feature but it's relatively easy to build into a custom module:

Write an observer for the `sales_order_place_before` event, it receives the (not yet saved) order object as a parameter so that you can do all your checks. To reject the order, throw an Exception. If it is a `Mage_Core_Exception` (like with `Mage::throwException($message)`) the user will see the exception message, if it is any other `Exception`, a generic message is shown:

> There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.